# how to call API from API using NSURLSession block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have

```
NSString* FBAuthoValue= @"TESTINGCONSTANT";
```

On click of Load Button ,it call HitLoadAPI

I am calling my API like below HitLoadAPI, now if at my server end my FBAuthoValue is change i need to Hit another API to get refresh value of FBAuthoValue, and set in HitLoadAPI.

1) User hit HitLoadAPI with FBAuthoValue= @"TESTINGCONSTANT" value, but as in server now FBAuthoValue= @"NewTestCode", so it return httpresponsecode 909,on 909 i need to call refreshFBAuthValue api, and put this value back to HitLoadAPI, and the api work correctly.

2) if FBAuthoValue token change in server, need to call refreshFBAuthValue API, and its return value need to set and call the HitLoadAPI again,without knowing the user.

**NOTE**: i have to hit multiple API one after another, suppose API-1,API-2,API-3 and so on, and if FBAuthoValue, if in any api ,changes in server then need to refresh that FBAuthoValue and then the same API need to be call, without effecting or blocking to user.
I will reward 50 bounty for sure.

Overview: API-1 call, in the meanwhile if token expire,need to call token expire api, and the API-1 will recall again, without user press Load Button again.

Here is my code

```
-(void)HitLoadAPI
{
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"[JSON SERVER"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:FBAuthoValue forHTTPHeaderField:FBAUTH];

NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TEST IOS", @"name",
                     @"IOS TYPE", @"typemap",
                     nil];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
 NSDictionary* headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
            //NSLog(@" headers =%@",headers);
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
            //NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);

            if([httpResponse statusCode]==909)
                {

              FBAuthoValue =[self refreshFBAuthValue];
                //what to do here so the current API hit will be call again....

                }


}];

[postDataTask resume];
}






 -(NSString *) refreshFBAuthValue
 {
 //hit api to get new refresh token code here need its calling code as well as the block coding cause it response so late which cause return value nil...to HitLoadAPI 
 return  FBaccess_token; //it will return refresh FBaccess_token code

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method which you can use to call any api from anywhere in the application, This method takes the parameter specific to an api call, like api url, data which will be included in the body of the request and a completion block which will be called when fbAuthValue is valid.

```
 -(void)HitAPILoadWithFbAuthValue:(NSString*)fbAuthValue apiUrl:(NSString*)apiUrl postData:(NSDictionary*)dict withCompletion:(void (^)(int statusCode,NSURLResponse * apiResponse,NSError * error))completion{
    NSError *error;

       NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
       NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrl];
       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                               timeoutInterval:60.0];

       [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
       [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
       [request setValue: fbAuthValue forHTTPHeaderField:FBAUTH];

        //post body with dictionary passed as a parameter
       NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary* headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
        //NSLog(@" headers =%@",headers);
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        //NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);

        if([httpResponse statusCode]==909)
            {

          FBAuthoValue =[self refreshFBAuthValue];
            //what to do here so the current API hit will be call again....
            if (FBAuthoValue){
                [self HitAPILoadWithFbAuthValue:fbAuthValue apiUrl:apiUrl postData:dict withCompletion:completion];
            }else{
            }

            }
         //if FbAuthValue is valid, call completion block
         completion((int)[httpResponse statusCode],response, error);


     }];

      [postDataTask resume];
     }
```

**Usage**
I assume you write this method in a separate class called APIManager. So to call this method  first create an instance of the APIManager and call like this:

```
   APIManager *sharedManager = [APIManager sharedInstance]

    //call API_1
   [sharedManager HitAPILoadWithFbAuthValue:FBAuthValue apiUrl:@"API_1_URL" postData:dict_for_first_api withCompletion:^(int statusCode, NSURLResponse *apiResponse, NSError *error) {

    if(error != nil){
     //handle error here
    }else{

        //call API_2
        [sharedManager HitAPILoadWithFbAuthValue:FBAuthValue apiUrl:@"API_2_URL" postData:dict_for_second_api withCompletion:^(int statusCode, NSURLResponse *apiResponse, NSError *error) {

        }];
    }

}];
```

Comment: i have a common class for all API handling , how to do it there?

Comment: The same approach will be apply to every method to call it recursively for a matched condition. and there must be an exit point in the method so that it don't enter in a loop.

Comment: need   [self thismethodisnotfixecanchange: FBAuthoValue];

Comment: don't need to write repeated code everywhere, and change in my all application code, just need to put it in my API code class to handle it, as i write my API class separate to handle.

Comment: You don't need to write it everywhere, you can place this method in your API class and call it form everywhere .

Comment: any alternative to resolve it in the same API class? as Android guys do it in the same API class?

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope this will resolve your problem